# __init__.py があると、”Unable to import '○○○'pylint(import-error)" になる

Tags: python, python3, vscode, anaconda, anaconda3

ソースコードは以下の通りです。
aaa.py

```
class aaa(object):
  __slots__ = ['_first']
  def __init__(self):
    self._first = ''
```

bbb.py

```
import aaa as a

class bbb(a.aaa):
  __slots__ = ['_name']
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self._name = ''
    pass

  pass
```

**ファイル構成が以下の場合には問題ありません。**
(問題がないというのは**pylintのエラーにならない**ということです)
(かつ、**bbb.pyを実行してもエラーにならない**。)

```
└─forTest
    │  aaa.py
    │  bbb.py
    │
    └─__pycache__
            aaa.cpython-37.pyc
```

[image: pylintエラーなし]

---

ところが、以下のように**__init__.pyを追加**すると

```
└─forTest
    │  aaa.py
    │  bbb.py
    │  __init__.py
    │
    └─__pycache__
            aaa.cpython-37.pyc
```

**pylintのエラーが発生**するのです。
[image: pylintのエラーが発生する]
[image: pylintのエラー内容]

---

そこで、
**import aaa as a >>>> from . import aaa as a**
にすると、エラーにはなりません。

[image: fromだとエラーは発生しない]

ですが、**このbbb.pyを実行するとエラーになる**のです。

cannnot import name 'aaa' from '`__main__`'

[image: cannot import]

---

ここまできてわからなくなりました。
pylilntのエラーにならず、
bbb.pyを実行してもimportできるようにするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

---

環境
vscode:1.42.1
Python: 3.7.3 32-bit('base':conda)

pylint --version の結果は以下の通り。

pylint 2.3.1
astroid 2.2.5
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 13:20:13) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]

---

conda update --all の後
pylint --version の結果は以下の通り。

pylint 2.4.4
astroid 2.3.3
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 16:21:45) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: `__init__.py` の中身はどうなっていますか？ それとも空(から/empty)でしょうか？

Comment: 空(から/empty)です。

Comment: それでは `__init__.py` に `from .aaa import aaa` を記述して、`bbb.py` では `import aaa as a` とするとどうなるでしょうか。

Comment: お疲れ様です。python3.7.2 pylint2.4.4で、ご指摘のエラーが出ません。

Comment: @metropolis 実装してみましたがだめでした。

Comment: こちらは python 3.7.5 ですが、前述の設定でエラーは発生しません。ところで、`__pycache__` ディレクトリ内のファイル(*.pyc)は削除しましたか？

Comment: @metropolis
pylintを最新にし、
__init__.py に from .aaa ****
bbb.py に import aaa  ****
実装しましたが、pylintのエラーは発生します。
"Unable to import 'aaa' pylint(import-error)"

Comment: @boundary1 
conda update -all で全部更新しましたがだめでした。

Comment: cannnot import name 'aaa' from '__main__'とかは、相対インポートの話だと思います。パッケージならばセーフかと。そうなると、もともとの問題も、どういう環境で、pylintを実行しているかとかの問題になるのでしょうか？

Comment: __init__.pyは空のままで、bbb.pyのimport aaa as aの代わりにimport sys改行import os改行sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))改行from forTest import aaa as aを追加したとき、エラーは解消しませんか？　※pylintは試していません。

Comment: お疲れ様です。難問ですね。これ、何の検討になってますかね。無理やり、この条件でもエラーが出ない検討？なんか、pylintの使い方（環境）の問題のような気が。。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

無理です。両立しません。

`__init__.py`を置いた時点で「forTestディレトリをパッケージとして取り扱う」と**プログラマが意図している**ことになります。
そうすると、そこに置いている`bb.py`は「forTestパッケージのファイル」として取り扱えとプログラマがPythonにそう**指示している**ことになります。`bb.py`はforTestディレクトリをカレントにして実行するファイルではありませんよ、ということです。

だから、
`from aaa as s`と書くとpylintのエラーが発生します。「パッケージとして取り扱う」という意図に反するからです。
`from . import aaa as a`と書くとpylintのエラーは消えます。「パッケージとして取り扱う」という意図に沿うからです。で、そうするとそこをカレントにしての実行はできません。

---

全体の構成として
パッケージ扱いにしない
か
実行するpyファイルがある場所をカレントとして見て、その下にパッケージとして取り扱うディレクトリ群を置く
かの選択になります。

---

後者を選んで`from . import aaa as a`と書いた場合でも、
forTestの**一つ上**をカレントディレクトリにして、`python -m forTest.bb`で実行する([参考](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options))
という方法はあります。